# How to modify value of a property in a json text in C#?

Tags: c#, json, .net-5

I have a service that receives some data with random structure in JSON format and persists these data in a document-based database. I have no control over sending services and there are some sensitive data that should not be persisted in my database. I just want to filter those fields and replace their values with some masking characters. Is there any built-in solution in dotnet5 without adding third-party libraries like json.net  or Json Newtonsoft?

I cannot deserialize incoming JSON to a static typed class because I have no idea about how many different types are sent from other services. An also working with reflection and dynamic typing has its own performance penalties.

Comment: System.Text.Json isn't "built-in" enough for you?

Comment: I could not find any reference that shows there are any tools or classes to modify a JSON value such as JObject in json.net and newtonsoft.

Comment: How do you plan to identify the sensitive data?

Comment: searching for some sensitive name such as password, token, etc.

Comment: So, what *do* you know about the incoming data? e.g. *"It's got an attribute `"password":"abc123"` "* - regex replace?

Comment: I think you need to write a custom JSonConverter ... https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/system-text-json-converters-how-to?WT.mc_id=DT-MVP-5004074&pivots=dotnet-6-0

Comment: JSON is coming from external services and  I cannot change their JSON serialization approach.

Comment: Read the article, it's titled serialization, but explains custom serialization/DESERIALIZATION Methods.

Comment: If you need some help , you have to post the examples of json you already have  and what json you like to have instead

Comment: I am thinking about using JSON to replace the current value with a masked one, I think it is the straightest way.

Answer (score 0):

if you don't have any way to change in code, you can handle it in sql at the time of json insert.
like:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.InsertJson(@doc  NVARCHAR(MAX))
AS BEGIN
  INSERT INTO Person (id, name, surname, age)
  SELECT id, firstNAme, lastName, age
  FROM OPENJSON(@json)
       WITH (id int, firstName nvarchar(50), lastName nvarchar(50),age int)
END
```

Comment: I think it's a nosql db, btw

Answer (score 0):

I finally used regex to find and make masked using this code snipped.

```
 private string GetMaskedJson(string json, string[] fieldNames)
        {
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(json)) return string.Empty;
            foreach (var field in fieldNames)
            {
                var pattern = "\""+field+"\"\\s*:\\s*(\"?)(.+?)((\")|\\,|\\})";
                var maskedValue = "===MASKED VALUE===";
                var r = new Regex(pattern);
                var k = r.GetGroupNames(); 
                var t = Regex.Matches(json, pattern);
                //R
                foreach (var ma in t.Reverse().ToList())
                {
                    var masked = maskedValue; 
                    if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(ma.Groups[1].Value)) masked = $"\"{maskedValue}\""; 
                    json = json.Remove(ma.Groups[2].Index, ma.Groups[2].Length)
                        .Insert(ma.Groups[2].Index, masked);
                }
            }

            return json;
        }
```